# How to calculate f(2) measure?

Tags: math, statistics, information-retrieval

I'm trying to calculate f(0.5) and f(2) for this set of data:

```
Precision: 0.6
Recall: 0.45
```

My results:

```
f(1)  : 0.51
f(0.5): 0.56 (wrong)
f(2)  : 0.47 (wrong)
```

I calculated f(1) Measure using this formula

```
(2x(PxR))/(P+R)
```

**But when I try to calculate f(2) or f(0.5) my results are slightly off**

```
f(0.5) should be 0.54
f(2)   should be 0.49
```

I used the following formula:

```
(b^2 + 1) x ((P x R)/(b^2)+R)
```

b = the f measure I'm using, either 0.5 or 2

What am I doing wrong?
And if possible, could someone calculate the f(0.5) and f(2) measure for me and confirm that I am wrong?

Any help is appreciated, will do my best to make this question as clear as possible. Please leave a comment if it's not clear enough and I will try to add to it

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the same results. For F(2), `(b^2 + 1) x ((P x R)/(b^2)+R)` = `5 x (0.27/4+R)` = `5 x (0.0675+0.45)` = `5 x (0.0675+0.45)` = `5 x 0.5175` = `2.5875'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, [Wikipedia is searchable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#F-measure)

The correct equation (on the Wikipedia page it has real math formatting, which is easier to read) is:

`F(β)=(1+β2)⋅(PR/(β2P+R))`

Or in Python:

```
>>> def F(beta, precision, recall):
...   return (beta*beta + 1)*precision*recall / (beta*beta*precision + recall)
...
>>> F(1, .6, .45)
0.5142857142857143
>>> F(2, .6, .45)
0.4736842105263158
>>> F(0.5, .6, .45)
0.5625000000000001
```

That looks pretty close to the values you are getting, and not very similar to the ones you say are "correct". So it seems worth asking "Where do the supposedly correct values come from?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the same formula I've used, I just didn't know how to write it the same way on a pc. And the answers are from a past exam paper with solutions, thanks for also calculating the F2 and F0.5, at least I know that I've done it right, I was stuck on this for two hours!